# Bind more then one element to the same onclick

Tags: javascript

I'm so used to jQuery that it's scary I cant do this.

I want to bind more elements to the same `onlick` with javascript. This only binds the first item, I tried `querySelectorAll` that wont bind any of them.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0g54u21/1/)

```
<div data-overlay></div>
<div data-overlay></div>
<div data-overlay></div>
<div data-overlay></div>

document.querySelector('[data-overlay]').onclick = function() {
    console.log('I'm clicked');
}
```

Comment: I would really suggest using jquery not only does it make it easier to do this but it also helps with cross browser compatibilities

Comment: Strict no jQuery policy for the current project. We are on ie9+ @CraigWayne

Comment: Oh jesus, didn't even read the first line of your post. Apologies

Comment: It happends, get more coffe ;) @CraigWayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

### The "Probably Practically Best" - a.k.a. event delegation

```
var handler = function(event) {
  console.log("I'm clicked");
};

// Register an event on the body, all clicks on the document are captured.
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Check if the click occurred on an element we care about
  if (event.target.dataset.overlay !== undefined) {
    // Call the handler if it is.
    handler.call(this, event);
  }
});
```

Works in all major browsers, since IE11 which supports `HTMLElement.dataset`, you can probably use `getAttribute` for earlier support.

### The Modern

```
var handler = () => {
  console.log("I'm clicked");
};

// This line makes it work in older versions of modern browsers.
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] 
  || Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]; 

for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('[data-overlay]')) {
  el.addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

### The Slightly Less Modern

```
var handler = () => {
  console.log("I'm clicked");
};

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-overlay]'), el =>
    el.addEventListener('click', handler));
```

### The "I need to support internet explorer"

```
var handler = function() { console.log("I'm clicked"); };
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-overlay]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

---

- Note that Event Delegation works best if you have many matching elements (hundreds), or if matching elements can appear and disappear from the DOM at any given time.
- Note that with Event Delegation, you don't have to bind the event on the body, you can use the **highest known ancestor**, if all `[data-overlay]` elements are under the same parent (or grandparent), you can bind the event to that.
- Note how I used `addEventListener` and not `.onclick`, using event attributes is considered a bad practice because you can't add more than one function, even if you wanted to (`addEventListener` has no such limitation).

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on how it works if they have a parent, how would I bind to that (lets say the container has `class="container"`

Comment: The event delegation part involves registering the event on an ancestor, and then checking `e.target` (which is the actual element that was the target of the event) if it satisfies a predicate. Look up "event delegation" on Google for more details.

Comment: A little convoluted maybe Madara? please dont kill me

Comment: @CraigWayne There are techniques to improve the API, for example, jQuery's API asks you for a selector, then does exactly that, binds to the `document` and checks if the element matches the selector. It's just better at hiding that detail away from you, it's not really hard to write a function `addEventToSelector(selector, event, callback) {` that does the same thing, and hide the details from the consumer.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-overlay]')
var elementArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( elements );
elementArray .forEach(function(element){
   element.onclick = function() {
      console.log("I'm clicked");
   }
})
```

Comment: shoulden't it be `elementArray.forEach()`?